# SQL select distinct min and max records from date and lowest and highest values

Tags: php, mysql, date

Let's say i have a table like this:

```
id  |  date               | price
-------------------------------
1   | 2018-03-06 22:19:10 | $10   
2   | 2018-03-06 13:16:19 | $12 
3   | 2018-03-06 00:12:11 | $18 
4   | 2018-03-05 23:29:10 | $10 
5   | 2018-03-05 03:16:19 | $05 
6   | 2018-03-05 00:11:11 | $11
```

I want to retrieve distinct date , and for each distinct date its first result (like lowest hour) and its related price and the latest result (like highest hour) and its related price.
I also need to retrieve the highest and lowest price for each distinct date.

Is it possible doing this with a single query? If yes, how?
What I tried is using distinct(date) but, since there are different hours, it returns all the results. I also tried Trunc but does not work.

```
Sample result:
date        min_price   max_price   lowest_hour_price   highest_hour_price
2018-03-06  $10         $18         $18                 $10
```

Comment: Don't store '$'. Distinct isn't a function. And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: pls show us your expected result or output. Thanks

Comment: i don't know how to edit, but expected output is: price at lowest hour of the day, price at highest hour of the day, highest price of all hours of  the day, lowest price of all hours of the day. this for each UNIQUE day. @anonyXmous

Comment: You can press the edit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using mySql 5.6 and this query works:

```
select date(m.min_max_date) as date,
   max(case when m.lbl='min_hr_price' then m.min_max_hr_price else null end) as lowest_hr_price,
   max(case when m.lbl='max_hr_price' then m.min_max_hr_price else null end) as max_hr_price,
   max(case when n.lbl='min_price' then n.min_max_price else null end) as min_price,
   max(case when n.lbl='max_price' then n.min_max_price else null end) as max_price
from (select 'min_hr_price' as lbl, price as min_max_hr_price, date as min_max_date 
  from tbl 
  where date in (select min(date) as min_date from tbl group by date(date))
union 
select 'max_hr_price', price, date   
  from tbl 
  where date in (select max(date) as max_date from tbl group by date(date))) as m,
(
select 'min_price' as lbl,
min(date) as min_max_date,
min(price) as min_max_price
from tbl
group by date(date)
union
select 'max_price' as lbl,
max(date) as min_max_date,
max(price) as min_max_price
from tbl
group by date(date)
) n
where m.min_max_date=n.min_max_date
group by date(m.min_max_date)
order by m.min_max_date

Sample result:
date        lowest_hr_price max_hr_price    min_price   max_price
2018-03-06  $1102.8         $1821           $1011.6     $1821

INSERT INTO TBL VALUES(1, '2018-03-06 22:19:10', '$1011.6');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES(2, '2018-03-06 13:19:11', '$1011.6');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES(3, '2018-03-06 03:21:25', '$1106.2');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES(4, '2018-03-06 00:26:50', '$1102.8');
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES(5, '2018-03-06 22:26:17', '$1821');
```

Comment: I also need price at lowest hour of the day, price at highest hour of the day.

Comment: i updated my answer. Long, ugly but working. Thanks.

Comment: It's weird tho...i tried with some prices , i've inserted: 1011.6 , 1106.2 , 1821, 1102.8 . It takes min_price and max_price correctly, but lowest_hour_price 0 and highest_hour_price 9.51 , which are values not existing . How is it possible?

Comment: Show me all your data on that specific date then we will double check it. Thanks

Comment: price 1011.6 | date 2018-03-06 22:19:10, price 1011.6 | date 2018-03-06 13:19:11, price 1106.2 | date 2018-03-06 03:21:25, price 1102.8 | date 2018-03-06 00:26:50, price 1821 | date 2018-03-06 22:26:17

Comment: I don't see any problem on this data. I get the correct result. date lowest_hr_price max_hr_price min_price max_price
2018-03-06 $1102.8 $1821 $1011.6 $1821

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, thank you a lot. I keep having that different behaviour by the way, i don't know why. Could it be because i have a where clause in addition? Before group by date(date_time) i have 'WHERE category = 1'.